# With external display, screen turns black after start from suspend Xubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, display, xubuntu, suspend-resume

I work with a Thinkpad X220 and have Xubuntu 11.10 installed. Everything works fine, except for this;

When I suspend my laptop, while it is connected to my external monitor (either cloned screen or only using the external monitor), it gives a blank screen when coming out of suspend. I can still see my mouse moving, but both screens remain blank.

Only a hard reset fixes the issue. Returning it to suspend (by closing laptop) does nothing. Both screens remain inactive (black, but with mouse pointer) after wakeup from suspend/sleep.

Some further information;

A)
I have memorized the "Display settings" command. When I press the command sequence on my keyboard to 1) show only laptop screen and then 2) show only the external screen, my display (on the external monitor) returns and I can proceed as normal. But I have to do this every time, and when I make one mistake I am lost (as I cannot see the output unless I do it completely right).

B)
I have now installed the gui interface "grandr" and edited to e.g. show only my external monitor or a dual screen setup (depending on my preferences).
Now, when I put my laptop to sleep/suspend, both displays work normally (dual or only single external display) after resuming from sleep or suspend.
- So I guess the is sort of a solution, but it requires you to install grandr and not to use the Xubuntu display settings menu.

Maybe someone has a better solution or fix?

Comment: My x220 and T61 are experiencing exactly the same problem! I'll try your methods later. By chance, I tried out a couple of distros. I found Ubuntu, Mint and LMDE all have this problem, while fedora 16 does not. So I kind of feel it is related with the default settings or video driver of Debian based linux. Hopefully someone could help figure out the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-monitor support upgraded in Ubuntu 12.04 beta1. I tried out the live CD. suspend/resume works flawlessly.

Comment: Indeed, under Xubuntu 12.04 I no longer experience this issue. Great, thanks developers!

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Toshiba Sat Pro which had the same problem...i cured it by entering the bios at boot and disabling the LAN at boot up....now it comes out of suspend everytime